# How to create QR code image with company logo

Tags: api, qr-code

We are using a lot of QR code around our office. I would like to know if we can generate QR code with a small company logo in the middle. I have seen few examples online.

But I want it to generate it automatically instead of user manually editing it with photoshop software.

I appreciate any help.

Thanks.

Comment: http://www.qrcode-monkey.com/ is one place you can create it.

Comment: There is a post related to it: http://twainscanning.com/how-to-customize-qr-code-add-a-logo-to-it/ . It introduced several ways to do it, either via some online website like qrcode-monkey.com , or using MS PowerPoint or Photoshop.

Comment: You could quickly generate lots of custom QR codes with: https://github.com/bitjson/qr-code –  just include the script for the web component in an `.html` document and add `<qr-code contents="your contents here"></qr-code>` anywhere on the page. You can set colors and a logo in the center, and the resulting QR codes will be rendered with SVG, so they'll remain sharp even when printed at very large sizes.

Answer (score 16):

You can try http://www.unitaglive.com/qrcode. 
It allows many content types and heavy customization, including changing the color of the eyes; using an image as the background; many styles; shadow; redundancy; and more, also allows you to use a logo and is based off a freemium business model. The free plan has no signup

Comment: +1 This site just works.

Comment: Very well made site for QR Code customization! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 13):

Here is a site that will generate a QR code with your image actually embedded as part of the QR code, no error correction.

http://research.swtch.com/qr/draw

There is some information about how it is done here if you wanted to look into implementing the logic yourself for automation.

http://research.swtch.com/qart

Comment: These links seem to be no longer active :-(

Comment: Sorry, only the first link isn't working

Answer (score 5):

http://beqrious.com/generator and then the graphical tab

Answer (score 5):

I created a video showing how to use an open-source c# library to create a QR Code and then upload/embed a logo of your choosing into the QR Code:

http://markhagan.me/Samples/Create_QR_Code_With_Logo_ASPNet

The video is only 10 minutes long and the result is a working QR Code generator. In case you don't care to spend the ten minutes, here is the source code:

The front page:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="default.aspx.cs" Inherits="CodeCreator._default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:TextBox ID="URL" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <br /><br />
        <asp:FileUpload ID="LogoUpload" runat="server" />
        <br /><br />
        <asp:Button ID="CreateCode" runat="server" Text="Create QR Code" OnClick="CreateCode_OnClick" />
        <br /><br />
        <asp:Image runat="server" ID="QRImage" />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

And the code-behind:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

using MessagingToolkit.QRCode.Codec;
using MessagingToolkit.QRCode.Codec.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;

namespace CodeCreator
{
    public partial class _default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        protected void CreateCode_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string path = "c:\\code\\projects\\CodeCreator\\CodeCreator\\";
            QRCodeEncoder encoder = new QRCodeEncoder();

            encoder.QRCodeErrorCorrect = QRCodeEncoder.ERROR_CORRECTION.H; // 30%
            encoder.QRCodeScale = 10;

            Bitmap img = encoder.Encode(URL.Text);
            LogoUpload.SaveAs(path + LogoUpload.FileName);

            System.Drawing.Image logo = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(path + LogoUpload.FileName);

            int left = (img.Width / 2) - (logo.Width / 2);
            int top = (img.Height / 2) - (logo.Height / 2);

            Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(img);

            g.DrawImage(logo, new Point(left, top));

            img.Save(path + "img.jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);

            QRImage.ImageUrl = "img.jpg";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You may want to look at http://contentdeveloper.com/2010/01/how-to-customize-qr-codes-with-your-brands-identity/ (there were some other articles I read just a couple nights ago, but I can't find them, though this should work as well)...also, something I read suggested using the highest error correction level. This way, more of the data in the barcode is merely error-correction data. You can overwrite this with no worries, as long as you realize that if the rest of the barcode gets damaged, you may not be able to recover the data.

Unfortunately, it's just going to involve a bunch of trial and error.

Good luck!

EDIT: Sorry, I just read that you wanted it generated automatically rather than editing the image.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use directly your logo with LogoGrab. Just upload your logo at http://www.logograb.com/upload, link any content you wish to your logo and let your customers scan your logo wherever they see it.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the following sites. They allow you upload a logo or graphic and have it automatically embedded in the QR code. They also support color changes.

- http://qr.odoa.eu
- http://blog.qr4.nl

I believe the QR4 site is working on an API to allow others to offer the same services in their websites.

Hope the above links help in solving your problem.