# How can I generate a circular qr-code like a messenger or a kik code?

Tags: qr-code

How can you generate the codes like shown below:

[image: How can I generate a circular qr-code like a messenger or a kik code?]

Comment: [qr-codes.png](https://postimg.org/image/55nr1ajt7/)

Comment: Snapcode is easy, but they lawyers will try to threaten you https://feelinsonice-hrd.appspot.com/web/deeplink/snapcode?username=FlixBusOfficial&type=SVG

Comment: no dice so far...

Comment: Hi, got any solution?, I am trying

Answer (score 8):

I will assume you want to use an existing standard instead of attempting to invent your own encoder\decoder.

Any 2D barcode can be intentionally damaged for esthetics if you crank up the redundancy used for error correction. 2D barcodes are designed to survive a certain amount of damage. Placing an image in the center and rounding the corners are both considered damage from the perspective of the reader. For round corners you can't use a barcode with orientation dots in the corners, like QR. You must choose a format that is oriented with a marker in the middle like:

### MaxiCode

[image: MaxiCode]
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MaxiCode

### ShotCode

[image: ShotCode]
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ShotCode

### Aztec Code

[image: Aztec Code]
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aztec_Code

Similarly, if you wanted to place an image in the center then you wouldn't want to use one that requires a bullseye for orientation, unless you can retain the bullseye somehow in your central image. To place an image in the center and also round the corners you need to get creative. In your first image there are four tracking dots around the image. In the second and third examples the company uses it's own logo as the orientation point.

Comment: thanks so much, @HackSlash! this is extremely promising.

Picking up from your answer, are you aware of encoding schemes that allow for a non-central / off-center bullseye placement, relatively close to the center or alternatively, a distributed tracking system that isn't positioned at the far corners?

Or worst case, even if not circular, a scheme that is guaranteed to not place any markers or encoded information on a consistent area of the image that can be utilized for a logo?

Comment: Here are some examples with QR, which is square: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3339202/how-to-create-qr-code-image-with-company-logo

Comment: Do some trial and error testing. Make an image, ensure that it scans, then make modifications and see how stylized you can make it while retaining functionality. Keep in mind that not all readers are equal. Be sure to test with your target scanning device. A cell phone will be limited by the camera quality. A handheld scanner will always be better than a cell phone.

Comment: Just a note on the Kik code, the logo is not used at all for orientation, you can test it by covering up the entire centre and it will still scan fine

Answer (score 1):

The first code you show is a [proprietary code](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/discovery/messenger-codes/) made by Facebook. It is now no longer used by their products, but some sites, e.g. [respond.io](https://respond.io/blog/facebook-messenger-code/) may allow you to create them and some regular QR code scanners may be able to read them.

The second code is a Snapchat code and can be made on [their site](https://scan.snapchat.com/) directly when you log into your account. You can also do it the the app on your device using their [support instructions](https://support.snapchat.com/en-US/a/about-snapcodes) within [limits](https://support.snapchat.com/en-US/a/snapcode-guidelines) for success.

The third code is a Kik code and there is a [blog post](https://www.kik.com/blog/a-code-definitely-worth-following/#:%7E:text=How%20do%20you%20create%20a,Kik%20Code%20for%20your%20bot) of how to make that possible by generating a key and then downloading the code image in the color of your choice. They have [more posts](https://www.kik.com/blog/what-are-kik-codes/) about how to work with them.

With all that said and done, you could try a site (not affiliated) like [QR Code Go](https://qrcodego.com/) to make regular QR codes that are a little fancy. Thank you. Good day.